# How to get the expected answer

Tags: c

I have input the values of `d = 10` `s = 5` and `h = 4` and I got a different output than expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float d,s,h;
    printf ("enter values:");
    scanf("%f %f %f",& d,&s,&h);
           
    double E= sqrt((2*d*s)/h);
    printf ("E=%lf\n",E);
           
    double T=sqrt((2*s)/d*h);
    printf ("T=%lf\n",T);
           
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output

```
E = 5
T = 0.5
```

What I get

```
E = 5
T = 2
```

Comment: I don,t know if this is a copy typo, but there's a space between the '%' and 'd' : `scanf("%f %f %f",& d,&s,&h);`.

Comment: What answer do you expect?

Comment: I get T = 2 when I run your code at http://cpp.sh/.

Comment: Based on what's there, this result looks correct.

Comment: I think you want T=sqrt((2*s)/(d*h)); , then you will get what you're expecting.

Comment: My suspicion is that it's an associativity issue. `sqrt((2*5)/10*4)` gives 2, while `sqrt((2*5)/(10*4))` gives 0.5.

Answer (score 3):

```
double T=sqrt((2*s)/d*h);
```

> '/' and '*' has same precedence so the order of evaluation is left to
> right.
>
> so first (2xs) = 10 next 10/10 = 1; at last 1x2 = 2;
>
> Hence T is 2.

For more info - [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-precedence-and-associativity-in-c/#:~:text=Operator%20precedence%20determines%20which%20operator,one%20operators%20with%20different%20precedence.&text=Operators%20Associativity%20is%20used%20when,Right%20or%20Right%20to%20Left](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-precedence-and-associativity-in-c/#:%7E:text=Operator%20precedence%20determines%20which%20operator,one%20operators%20with%20different%20precedence.&text=Operators%20Associativity%20is%20used%20when,Right%20or%20Right%20to%20Left).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I am getting E=5  and T=0.5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float d,s,h;
    printf ("enter values:");
    scanf("%f %f %f",&d, &s, &h);
           
    double E = sqrt((2*d*s)/h);
    printf ("E=%lf\n",E);
           
    double T = sqrt((2*s)/(d*h));
    printf ("T=%lf\n",T);
}
```

This is the output I got

```
E=5.000000                                                                                                                                                     
T=0.500000
```